# Retrieve value from AnyObject to check against a particular constraint in Swift

Tags: swift, anyobject

I have an object that is returned as an AnyObject from a 3rd party SDK, which I have no control over.

The stream gives me a collection of bluetooth devices, and comes in the flavour of:

```swift
AnyObject
  object [__NSDictionaryM]
     [0] = "dataElement" : 4 key/value pairs
     [1] = "MACAddress" : ""
     [2] = "idString" : ""
     [3] = "peripheral": hex_string
     [4] = "localName" : "Unnamed"
     [5] = "RSSI" : "-40"
```

I want to check if the device is already contained in another list, by `localName`, and if not, to add it to my alternate list.

However, I don't want to write a loop on deviceList and then another loop on the element in the loop, just to get to the name; this is counter intuitive, where in a language like C# you can just do deviceList["localName"] to get the value.

As I'm not Swift expert, and having tried casting it to various forms of NSDictionary without success, was wondering if there is a way I can do this without nested loops?

[image]

Comment: `if let dictionary = someObject as? [String: Any] {…` might work. And then `if let localName = dictionary["localName"] as? String {…`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i tried that, then it just turns the ```object``` part into something like ```[0] ((key: String, value: Any)) > key = (String) "Whatever" > value: (String) "Whatever"```, which leaves me with the exact same situation of having nested loops :$. Swift makes no sense

Comment: Well maybe it is an array of dictionaries then [[String:Any]]. Many things doesn’t make sense when you don’t understand them.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson exactly :D, trying to understand. i didn't consider [[ ]]. good point. thanks. let me try that and see what happens. thank you